# Trying to add an array to an associated array

Tags: php, database, wordpress, associative-array

I have an associated array saved in my database that Im saving to a variable called `response_cost` using the Wordpress function `get_post_meta`.

```
$response_cost = get_post_meta( $postID, $metaKey, true );
```

The array looks something like this:

```
a:2: {
    i:0;a:3:
        {s:4:"type";s:6:"months";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:1:"=";}
    i:1;a:3:
        {s:4:"type";s:5:"weeks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:1:"+";}
}
```

I have a form that I've created which outputs a new array and it's saved in a variable called `$add_to_response_cost`.

```
$add_to_response_cost = array (
    'type' => $type,
    'cost' => $cost,
    'modifyer' => $modifyer
);
```

I'm can't figure out how to add `$add_to_response_cost` as another instance of `$response_cost` so that the out put ends up like so:

```
a:3: {
    i:0;a:3:
        {s:4:"type";s:6:"months";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:1:"=";}
    i:1;a:3:
        {s:4:"type";s:5:"weeks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:1:"+";}
    i:2;a:3:
        { my new array I've constructed via $add_to_response_cost }
}
```

Any help or direction with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the problem, first we need to explain a little about how saving arrays in custom fields works

Here we have an array

```
$array = array(
     "0" => array(
       "type" => "months",
       "cost" => null,
       "modifier" => "=",
     ),
     "1" => array(
      "type" => "weeks",
      "cost" => null,
      "modifier" => "+",
)
);
```

If we decide to save it as a custom field in the database, we use the update_post_meta() function

```
update_post_meta( 1, 'response_cost', $array );
```

Before saving it to the database, Wordpress will [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) our array and then put it into the database.

As a result, the array will be saved in the database in the following format

> a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"type";s:6:"months";s:4:"cost";N;s:8:"modifier";s:1:"=";}i:1;a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"weeks";s:4:"cost";N;s:8:"modifier";s:1:"+";}}

Then, if we want to get an array, we use get_post_meta()

```
$myarray = get_post_meta(1, "response_cost", true);
```

Wordpress will take a serialized array from the database and convert it to a typical array.

Then we can add any data we want to the array and save it back to the database.

```
$add_to_response_cost = array (
    'type' => $type,
    'cost' => $cost,
    'modifyer' => $modifyer
);

$myarray[] = $add_to_response_cost;

update_post_meta( 1, 'response_cost', $myarray );
```

Usually this problem occurs when using the get_post_meta function without specifying a key, with only one parameter (ID), then we get arrays without processing and they must first be [unserialized](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php)

This can also happen when you get an array from a database not through a Wordpress function, but by direct SQL query to the database.
Then you need to unserialize the array first, add data to it and pack it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try unserialize() to convert it to array.

$result = unserialize($response_cost);

Print_r($result);